# Converting float to binary and vice versa

Tags: warning-messages

This code will convert float to binary:

```
m[x_] := Block[{a, b}, 
  b[x] := FromDigits[
    RealDigits[x, 2, Reverse[RealDigits[x, 2]][[1]]] [[1]]]; 
  a[x] := RealDigits[x, 2] [[1]][[
    Reverse[RealDigits[x, 2]][[1]] + 1 ;; 
     IntegerLength[FromDigits[RealDigits[x, 2] [[1]]]]]]; 
  If[Head[x] === Integer, 
   IntegerPart[
    ToExpression[
      StringJoin["0.", 
       ToString /@ Table[a[x][[i]], {i, 1, Length[a[x]]}]]] + b[x]], 
   ToExpression[
     StringJoin["0.", 
      ToString /@ Table[a[x][[i]], {i, 1, Length[a[x]]}]]] + b[x]]
  ]
```

but when i try to reverse it like 2^^m[anynumber] i get error : "Digit at position 1 is too large to be used in base 2"
any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Have you seen [`BaseForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseForm.html)? For example; `binaryNum = BaseForm[12.5, 2]` and back again with `BaseForm[binaryNum, 10]`.

Comment: @Edmund thanks i was not aware of it.  can you for example sum them?  BaseForm[12, 2]+BaseForm[12, 2] ? atleast you dont see the ugly underscore 2 :D

Comment: Not at my computer but just summed them in Wolfram Cloud from my phone.

Comment: another example is that when you wana sum the integers of the binary this function performs better :mmm = Map[m, {23, 43, 512, 532}]
mmm1 = BaseForm[#, 2] & /@ {23, 43, 512, 532}
nn = Table[
  IntegerDigits[QuotientRemainder[mmm, 1]][[i]][[1]], {i, 1, 
   Length[mmm]}]
nn1 = Table[
  IntegerDigits[QuotientRemainder[mmm1, 1]][[i]][[1]], {i, 1, 
   Length[mmm1]}]
Plus @@@ nn
Plus @@@ nn1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ToExpression["2^^" <> ToString[m[12]]]
```

> 12